# Render metadata from term store as dropdownbox

Tags: managed-metadata

Any idea how to render a managed metadata column as a dropdown list (just like the choice field)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just implemented a whole set of field controls for a publishing site where we replace the default metadata control with, dropdowns, checkboxes etc. Far easier for the end-user and we still want to manage the information as managed terms.

Just create a new field control inheriting from `BaseFieldControl (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls)` and customize its UI as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? If you create Managed Metadata column and have a flat term set (no nesting) you essentially get the same functionality...

Comment: Fewer clicks for the user. Say you have 5 fields, and you have no idea of what options are availible in each field. Then you first have to open the "metadata popup" and then select an item. That operation times 5 fields makes some extra clicks...